# smali - Неправильный код

Tags: android, smali, dalvik

Учу Dalvik Opcodes и вот, что набросал

```
.class public Lru/albatros/fr/MainActivity;
.super Landroid/app/Activity;
.source "MainActivity.java"

.field mPhone:Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone;
.field mIccCard:Lcom/android/internal/telephony/IccCard;
.field maker:Ljava/lang/Object;
.field a:Z
.method public constructor <init>()V
.locals 3

.prologue
.line 13
move-object v0, p0

move-object v2, v0

invoke-direct {v2}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V

return-void
.end method


.method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
.locals 5
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
    value = {
        "(",
        "Landroid/os/Bundle;",
        ")V"
    }
.end annotation

.annotation runtime Ljava/lang/Override;
.end annotation

.prologue
move-object v0, p0

move-object v1, p1

move-object v3, v0

const-string v4, "com.aide.ui"

invoke-static {v3, v4}, Ladrt/ADRTLogCatReader;->onContext(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 11
move-object v3, v0

move-object v4, v1

invoke-super {v3, v4}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

.line 12
move-object v3, v0

const v4, 0x7f030001

invoke-virtual {v3, v4}, Lru/albatros/fr/MainActivity;->setContentView(I)V

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory;->makeDefaultPhone(Landroid/content/Context;)V

invoke-static {}, Lcom/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory;->getDefaultPhone()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone;

move-result-object v5

iput-object v5, v3, Lru/albatros/fr/MainActivity;->mPhone:Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone;

invoke-interface {v5}, Lcom/android/internal/telephony/Phone;->getIccCard()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/IccCard;

move-result-object v5

iput-object v5, v3, Lru/albatros/fr/MainActivity;->mIccCard:Lcom/android/internal/telephony/IccCard;

return-void
.end method
```

Но при просмотре кода в Java получается так

```
package ru.albatros.fr;

import adrt.ADRTLogCatReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard;
import com.android.internal.telephony.Phone;
import com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
boolean a;
IccCard mIccCard;
Phone mPhone;
Object maker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    Phone phone;
    ADRTLogCatReader.onContext((Context)this, "com.aide.ui");
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    this.setContentView(2130903041);
    PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone((Context)this);
    this.mPhone = phone = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
    this.mIccCard = phone.getIccCard();
}
}
```

Что произошло с последними двумя строчками? Должно быть так

```
this.mPhone = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
this.mIccCard = mPhone.getIccCard();
```

Comment: зачем удалили дополнение?

Comment: Я опечатку исправил, и почти одновременно с Вашим добавлением изменение внес, и получилось, что Вы первее внесли. Но я потом добавил.

Comment: Прикол) Спасибо за правку

Comment: Выглядит как оптимизация при компиляции

Comment: как то сама создалась переменная `phone`, и потом используется. Что-то не так с регистрами, до сих пор причину не нашел